# Python client stops receiving socket data from host

Tags: python, sockets

I created a simple client/worker system where the host sends tasks to worker nodes using sockets.

Here's the host.py file:

```
import socket
import pickle

def assign_task(worker, task):
    worker.send(pickle.dumps(task))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    workers = []  # List to store worker connections

    # Create a socket for the host node
    host_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8888))
    host_socket.listen(5)

    print("Host node is listening for connections...")

    while True:
        # Accept incoming connections from workers
        worker_socket, addr = host_socket.accept()
        workers.append(worker_socket)
        print(f"Worker {addr} connected")

        # Assign tasks to workers
        tasks = ["task1", "task2", "task3"]
        for task in tasks:
            for worker in workers:
                assign_task(worker_socket, task)

    host_socket.close()
```

And here's the worker.py file:

```
import socket
import pickle
import time

def process_task(task):
    print(f"Received task: {task}")

    # Simulate processing time
    time.sleep(1)

    print(f"Task completed: {task}")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Create a socket for the worker node
    worker_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    worker_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))

    while True:
        # Receive tasks from the host
        task_data = worker_socket.recv(1024)
        if not task_data:
            break
        task = pickle.loads(task_data)
        process_task(task, args.latency)

    worker_socket.close()
```

Everything works fine on the worker node for the first few tasks, but stops after the second. This is the case regardless of the number of tasks in my list. The host appears to send all tasks out, regardless of the task list size, so the issue seems to be with the worker node. I'm not super familiar with sockets, so I'm honestly not sure what would be causing this issue. I've used RabbitMQ in the past with no issues, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to believe that `worker_socket.recv(1024)` is going to receive exactly one pickled object, no more and no less.  TCP is a *stream protocol*; the only guarantee it makes is that all of the bytes that were sent will be received in the same order.  You need a protocol on top of it to separate the original objects; perhaps a 2-byte length value, then call `.recv()` in a loop until you've received that exact length.